# using "if not some_list" is giving me a syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list I create with:

```
range_list = range(1,len(sequence.split(" "))-1)
```

given a string sequence of numbers: `"1 2 2 6 1"` for instance

When I run this:

```
if not range_list:
```

I am getting a syntax error (pointing at the colon).  What's the deal?

EDIT:

```
def jolly_jumper(sequence):

    index = 1
    range_list = range(1,len(sequence.split(" "))-1)

    for num in sequence.split(" ")[:1]:
        if(abs(int(num) - int(sequence.split(" ")[index])) > len(sequence.split(" ")) - 1 or abs(num - sequence.split(" ")[index]) == 0):
            print "Not Jolly"
        else: 
            filter(lambda a: a != abs(num - sequence.split(" ")[index], range_list)
            if not range_list:
                print "Jolly"
                break
```

Comment: Do you have anything on the line below?

Comment: Check for mismatched parentheses on nearby lines.

Comment: Could you be more elaborate? can't get an idea what you want to do

Comment: I included the whole algorithm now in the question.

Comment: `abs` is missing a closing paren

Comment: Also, `filter` returns a new list

Comment: Your code would be much cleaner if you saved `sequence.split(" ")` as its own variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `)` in this line:

```
    filter(lambda a: a != abs(num - sequence.split(" ")[index], range_list)
```

Should be like this:

```
    filter(lambda a: a != abs(num - sequence.split(" ")[index]), range_list)
```

Comment: Also, that line doesn't actually do anything to `range_list`, or have any other visible effects.

Comment: @user2357112 I know, but I don't really know the intentions of the OP.